# Why is my automatic chatbox not showing up?

Tags: javascript, css, this, addeventlistener

So when i click "chat with us", the full chat box must appear but it doesn't. The console announces mistake as:'*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
at HTMLButtonElement.* '
Anything wrong with my codes? somebody can help me? Thank you so much!

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Snake</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chat.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/48a972c999.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="chat-bar-collapsible">
        <button id="chat-bar-button" type="button" class="collapsible">Chat With Us!
            <i id="chat-icon" style="color: #fff;" class="fas fa-fw fa-comment-o"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="full-chat-block">
            <!--Mesage Container-->
            <div class="outer-container">
                <div class="container">
                    <!--Messages-->
                    <div id="chatbox">
                        <h5 id="chat-timestamp"></h5>
                        <p id="botStarterMessages " class="botText"><span>loading...</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <!--User Input Box-->
                    <div class="chat-bar-input-block">
                        <div id="user-input">
                            <input type="text" id="textInput" class="input-box" placeholder="Tap 'enter' to send a mesage" />
                            <p></p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="chat-bar-icons">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

</html>
```

This is my css:

```
.chat-bar-collapsible {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.collapsible {
    background-color: rgb(82, 151, 255);
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 350px;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    border-bottom: none;
}

.content {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.full-chat-block {
    width: 350px;
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    height: max-content;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.outer-container {
    min-height: 500px;
    bottom: 0%;
    position: relative;
}

.chat-container {
    max-height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    hyphens: auto;
}

.chat-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.chat-bar-input-block {
    display: flex;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
}

.chat-bar-icons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#chat-icon:hover {
    opacity: .7;
}


/* Chat bubbles */

#userInput {
    width: 75%;
}

.input-box {
    float: left;
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000;
    background-color: white;
    outline: none
}

.userText {
    color: white;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: right;
    clear: both;
}

.userText span {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #5ca6fa;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    max-width: 80%;
    margin-right: 10px;
    animation: floatup .5s forwards
}

.botText {
    color: #000;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: left;
}

.botText span {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    max-width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    animation: floatup .5s forwards
}

@keyframes floatup {
    from {
        transform: translateY(14px);
        opacity: .0;
    }
    to {
        transform: translateY(0px);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
    .full-chat-block {
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 0px;
    }
    .chat-bar-collapsible {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .collapsible {
        width: 100%;
        border: 0px;
        border-top: 3px solid white;
        border-radius: 0px;
    }
}
```

This is my JS:

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName('collapsible')

for (let i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.classList.toggle('active')

        var content = this.nextElementSibling

        if (content.style.maxHeight) {
            content.style.maxHeight = null
        } else {
            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px"
        }
    })
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `.nextSibling` will look directly for the next child element under your parent div. Since `this` refers to your button inside of `chat-bar-collapsible` there are no more child elements that are adjacent to your button element under the char-bar-collapsible div. You need to walk up to the parent element using `.parentNode`, and then access the adjacent `content` div from that using `.nextElementSibling`:

```js
var content = this.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
```

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName('collapsible');

for (let i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
    var content = this.parentNode.nextElementSibling;

    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px"
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.chat-bar-collapsible {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.collapsible {
  background-color: rgb(82, 151, 255);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 350px;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.full-chat-block {
  width: 350px;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  height: max-content;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.outer-container {
  min-height: 500px;
  bottom: 0%;
  position: relative;
}

.chat-container {
  max-height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  hyphens: auto;
}

.chat-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.chat-bar-input-block {
  display: flex;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
}

.chat-bar-icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#chat-icon:hover {
  opacity: .7;
}


/* Chat bubbles */

#userInput {
  width: 75%;
}

.input-box {
  float: left;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: white;
  outline: none
}

.userText {
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: right;
  clear: both;
}

.userText span {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #5ca6fa;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  animation: floatup .5s forwards
}

.botText {
  color: #000;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
}

.botText span {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  animation: floatup .5s forwards
}

@keyframes floatup {
  from {
    transform: translateY(14px);
    opacity: .0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .full-chat-block {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
  .chat-bar-collapsible {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .collapsible {
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px;
    border-top: 3px solid white;
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/48a972c999.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="chat-bar-collapsible">
  <button id="chat-bar-button" type="button" class="collapsible">Chat With Us!<i id="chat-icon" style="color: #fff;" class="fas fa-fw fa-comment-o"></i></button>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="full-chat-block">
    <!--Mesage Container-->
    <div class="outer-container">
      <div class="container">
        <!--Messages-->
        <div id="chatbox">
          <h5 id="chat-timestamp"></h5>
          <p id="botStarterMessages " class="botText"><span>loading...</span></p>
        </div>
        <!--User Input Box-->
        <div class="chat-bar-input-block">
          <div id="user-input">
            <input type="text" id="textInput" class="input-box" placeholder="Tap 'enter' to send a mesage" />
            <p></p>
          </div>

          <div class="chat-bar-icons">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```